# Error with not existing in current context and expected class

Tags: c#

so i'm relatively new to programming, it's my 1st class in the semester and now we are working with methods
have an assignment to write methods and here's my code
been messing with it for a while trying to get it executable to no avail
Here's my code

```
const double INTERNET_SPEED = 195.49;
const double PHOTO = 129.95;
const double KEYBOARD = 79.95;
const double MICROSOFT = 139.99;

private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        double charge = 0;
        double discountcharge = 0;
        double total;

        charge = GetPackageCharge(charge);
        discountcharge = GetDiscountCharge(discountcharge);
        total = DisplayCharges(charge, discountcharge);
        value returning method to determine price for selected packages

        if (nameTextBox.Text != "") // name input validation
        { 

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Customer Name.", "Name Required");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred!", "Error!");
        }
    }

    private double GetPackageCharge(double charge);
    double charge = 0;
    {
        //value returning method to determine price for selected packages
        if (internetCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            charge  = INTERNET_SPEED;
        }
        else if (photoCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            charge = PHOTO
        }
        else if (keyboardCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            charge = KEYBOARD;
        }
        else if microsoft.CheckBox.Checked)
        {
            charge = MICROSOFT;
        }
    }

    private void DisplayCharges(double charge, double discountcharge);
    {
        total = charge + discountcharge;
        packageLabel.Text = charge.ToString("C");
        discountLabel.Text = discountcharge.ToString("C");
        totalLabel.Text = total.ToString("C");
    }
}

private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //closes program
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: also i do have a GetDiscountCharge(double discountcharge); for radio button for Students and Regulars where students get 10% so charge = charge * 0.10 but it's not showing up correctly on the site

Comment: Please be more specific with your question - I'm not sure what you're after here. What's wrong with your current code? What is it currently doing, what *should* it be doing? What part of the code in particular do you think is causing the issue?

Comment: `private double GetPackageCharge(double charge);` is incorrect - remove the `;` and the following `double charge = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
private double GetPackageCharge(double charge);
    double charge = 0;
{
//value returning method to determine price for selected packages

if (internetCheckBox.Checked)
 {
charge  = INTERNET_SPEED;
 }

else if (photoCheckBox.Checked)
{
charge = PHOTO
}
else if (keyboardCheckBox.Checked)
{
charge = KEYBOARD;
}
else if microsoft.CheckBox.Checked)
{
charge = MICROSOFT;
}
}
```

to this:

```
private double GetPackageCharge(double charge)

{
//value returning method to determine price for selected packages
double charge = 0;
if (internetCheckBox.Checked)
 {
charge  = INTERNET_SPEED;
 }

else if (photoCheckBox.Checked)
{
charge = PHOTO
}
else if (keyboardCheckBox.Checked)
{
charge = KEYBOARD;
}
else if microsoft.CheckBox.Checked)
{
charge = MICROSOFT;
}

return charge;
}
```